# getting started with surfaceController in Umbraco 4.11

Tags: umbraco

I  want to read/write/Edit/Search data via surfaceController and views in Umbraco 4.11.

I know about SurfaceController. But i couldnt find any resources describing how to add SurfaceController to my Umbraco ?

Please Give me some links or steps to add SurfaceController to Umbraco and where to store this file in Umbraco Project?

Answer (score 0):

The [Umbraco Docs](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/) have a good reference on [Surface Controllers.](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers) You can create locally declared or plugin based controllers. Below is an example from the docs of a locally declared surface controller:

```
public class MySurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return Content("hello world");
    }
}
```

> All locally declared controllers get routed to:
>
> /umbraco/surface/{controllername}/{action}/{id}

Basically, the workflow is to create a new class library, add a class that inherits from `SurfaceController`, then build and deploy the dll to the bin directory of your Umbraco site.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating 1 project and add Umbraco with the Nuget Package Manager Console (Install-Package UmbracoCms -Version 6.0.3 ) ([Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/6.0.3)).

Then add a new project to your solution (a MVC3 or MVC4 project). Add your surface controller in the new project and copy (after building) the generated DLL and the views of your controller to the first project.

You can use the post build event to automate the copy process.

You can check http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/01/using-mvc-frontend-pages-in-umbraco-4-11-1/ if you want to create new frontend pages using MVC. The post is about Umbraco 4.11 but is still valid for Umbraco 6.0.x.